# scroll long data in fixed window size

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to create fix size window, so if the text from component `<Message/>` is longer (like in the attach image) I want it to scroll, on fixed window size.

Screenshot

[image]

```
export default function AllMessages(){
  ...
    return(
        <div className="message-style">
           ...  
            <div className="message-item">
                {messagesState.map(message => (
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <Message from = {message.sender} to = {message.receiver} subject = {message.subject} content = {message.message} date = {message.creationDate}/>
                    </ul>
                ))}
            ...
}
```

```
export default function Message(props){
    return(
             <li class="list-group-item">
                <div className="container-msg">
                    <div>
                        <h5>{props.from}</h5>
                        <h5>{props.to}</h5>
                        <p>{props.subject}</p>
                        <p>{props.content}</p>
                        <p>{props.date}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span className="mx-2 text-danger" /*onClick={handleDelete}*/>
                            <i className="fas fa-trash" />
                        </span>
                    </div>
             </div>
        </li>

    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set a height and max-height for the all message container div and then set overflow-y auto for example

```
.all-messages{
    height:500px;
    max-height:500px;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```